# iOS react-native-code-push app working in debug / release mode but white screen with archived TestFlight app

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm trying to use Microsoft Code Push to update the JS bundle without submitting the app to iTunes again.

On debug and release mode, the app can successfully load the bundle via Code Push and install updates at the next startup.

Unlike the debug / release Xcode app, when I archive the app and install it from TestFlight, I'm experiencing a white blank screen just after the native splashscreen. No crashes appears in the App Center.

I didn't used Cocoapod before adding Code Push support so I don't trust the Podfile and I'm a total newbie on this part.

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'yoga', path: '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'
  pod 'GLog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec'
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', subspecs: [
    'DevSupport',
  ]
  pod 'AppCenter/Crashes', '~> 1.7.1'
  pod 'AppCenter/Analytics', '~> 1.7.1'
  pod 'AppCenterReactNativeShared', '~> 1.6.0'
  pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'

  platform :ios, '9.0'
  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'MyApp-tvOS' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp-tvOS

  target 'MyApp-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

#### Environment

- react-native-code-push version: 5.4.0
- react-native version: 0.53.3
- iOS/Android/Windows version: iOS 10.2
- Does this reproduce on a debug build or release build? Nop, it's working perfectly
- Does this reproduce on a simulator, or only on a physical device? Works great on simulator

Comment: While seeing your pod file it seems like you have Crash/Analytics from AppCenter did you get anything there?

Comment: Unfortunately no, no crashes appears in the App Center.

Comment: Did you resolve this @Al3? I have a similar issue. In debug mode all works fine.  In release mode I get a blank white screen after the launch screen.  BUT the icons and functions on the screen work.  I can navigate from the white home screen to other screens and they appear fine.  Go back home, white screen.

Comment: @mediaguru similar issue here. not sure if it's the same but in my case everything works in sim and device debug, but my app is unresponsive in archive builds for a few minutes before accepting touches.

Comment: Any update on this? facing same white screen issue 
Codepush - v6.2.0
RN - 0.61.5

Comment: 2021 still having the same issue. I'm afraid to use Codepush so I'm not relying on Codepush for iOS. (Works on Android)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I just resolved with my TestFlight build.

I was able to deploy my app to my device locally with the react-native run-ios command and receive CodePush updates, but whenever I released the build for TestFlight, that app did not receive the updates.

The problem was my that my CodePush target version did not match the version in Xcode. You can fix this by changing the version under General -> Identity -> Version to match the target versions in CodePush. Or you can also change the deployed target version in CodePush to match the one from Xcode.

Additionally you can configure the CodePush target version in your deploy command by the -t flag and version number.
`appcenter codepush release-react -t '0.1.0' ...`